# Apt with client cert and HTTPS

Tags: apt, security

I have a (private) apt repository setup on a server. I'm only allowing access to this repository over SSL, and only with a client certificate. I have tested the connection using curl:

```
$ curl --cacert /opt/CA.crt --cert /opt/user.crt --key /opt/user.key
```

https://example.com/dists/lucid/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz
The content is downloaded as expected.

I've created a file in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/45example-com with

```
Debug::Acquire::https "true";

Acquire::https::example.com {
    Verify-Peer "false";
    Verify-Host "false";

    CaInfo "/opt/CA.crt";

    SslCert "/opt/user.crt";
    SslKey  "/opt/user.key";
};
```

I've added a file at /etc/apt/sources.list.d/example.com.list with:

> deb https://example.com/ lucid main

There seems to be a problem with the CA cert, when I try an update I get the following:

```
> apt-get update
> * Connected to example.com (8.0.0.8) port 443 (#0)
> * found 1 certificates in /opt/CA.crt
> * error reading X.509 key or certificate file
> * Closing connection #0
```

The server logs on example.com show that no request got there, so I guess that apt-get is failing before trying to send the request (which matches what the log says).

I've had a hard time finding any documentation on apt-get with ssl on the interwebs, and haven't even been able to find the source code.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Options/Solutions discussed in thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/166215/trouble-getting-apt-get-to-work-with-https isnt helping much, I still encounter the same errors.

Comment: what are the file permissions on /opt/CA.crt? Are you running selinux?

Comment: I tried almost every possible combinations, from 755, 744, to 444 right now its 755 and no I am not running selinux

Comment: To add with,  I could connect successfully with gnutls-cli and curl.

Answer (score 1):

This mostly happens with a directory permission issue, apt-get is very conscious on what the permission is set for keys and cert file, so setting a mere 777 or 644 would never work.

Steps described in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1668944 was very helpful to narrow down this issue.

I did the following steps to address this,

1. add _apt user to group ssl-cert

`~# usermod -G ssl-cert _apt`

2. Change the group of certs directory

`~# chgrp ssl-cert /opt/CA.crt /opt/user.crt /opt/user.key`

3. Fix the file permissions

`~# chmod 655 /opt/CA.crt /opt/user.crt /opt/user.key`

Also if this doesnt work for you, you can `su` as `_apt` and try to read your cert and key files, if you can then apt with client cert should work as expected.

Just to make sure if you are using self signed certificate, make sure you run

`~# sudo update-ca-certificates`

once you moved your ca certificate /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/